# Declare date, then add next business day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not getting the results that I need.

All I want to do is declare my date and then I want add the next business day to it.  ie. `@CASHDATE+1` (this works) but I need the next business day being 5th.

```
DECLARE  @CASHDATE DATETIME
SET @CASHDATE='2016-12-02'

SELECT <<COLUMN_NAME>>  FROM <<TABLE_NAME>> 
WHERE RECEIVED_DATE = @CASHDATE /*'2016-12-02'*/ 
AND TRANS_POST_DATE = @CASHDATE+1 /*'2016-12-05'*/) <== I don't want it to be '2016-12-03 or 04', I'm trying to get the next business day.
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be welcome.  I've been experimenting with `DATEPART(dw, @CASHDATE) NOT IN (1, 7)` but I just can't get the result I want.

Comment: Thanks all for posting your solutions they were perfect!  I can now complete my cash flow report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command DATEADD:

```
AND TRANS_POST_DATE = DATEADD (dd, 1, @CASHDATE)--@CASHDATE+1
```

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

make a function; It's easy... gime a minute... to make it

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>
-- =============================================
/*

declare @date datetime 
set @date = '2016-12-10'

declare @newDate datetime
select  @newDate = dbo.[GetBussinesDay](@date)

select @date, @newDate 

*/
create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBussinesDay]
(
    @Date as datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    declare @NewDate datetime

    declare @BussinessDays table ( bDay int)
    insert into @BussinessDays VALUES (2) --mon
    insert into @BussinessDays VALUES (3) --Tue
    insert into @BussinessDays VALUES (4) --Wed
    insert into @BussinessDays VALUES (5) --Thu
    insert into @BussinessDays VALUES (6) --Fri

    if exists(select bDay from @BussinessDays where bDay = DATEPART(dw,@Date))
    begin
        set @NewDate = @Date;
    end
    else
    begin
        set @NewDate = dbo.GetBussinesDay(dateadd(dd,1,@Date));
    end

    return @NewDate

END
```

Create the function and change your code:

```
AND TRANS_POST_DATE =  dbo.GetBussinesDay( @CASHDATE)--@CASHDATE+1
```

Also, you can change the bussines days in the function... for futures changes or rules.

Answer (score 4):

```
DATEADD(day,
    CASE
       WHEN DATENAME(dw,CASHDATE) = 'Friday' THEN 3
       WHEN DATENAME(dw,CASHDATE) = 'Saturday' THEN 2
       ELSE 1
    END,
    CASHDATE)
```

Here is an example to show you how it would calculate

```
DECLARE @Dates AS TABLE (CASHDATE DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES ('2016-11-28'),('2016-11-29'),('2016-11-30'),('2016-12-01'),('2016-12-02'),('2016-12-03'),('2016-12-04')

;WITH cteNextBizDays AS (
    SELECT
       CASHDATE
       ,NextBusinessDay = DATEADD(day,
          CASE
             WHEN DATENAME(dw,CASHDATE) = 'Friday' THEN 3
             WHEN DATENAME(dw,CASHDATE) = 'Saturday' THEN 2
             ELSE 1
          END
          ,CASHDATE)
    FROM
       @Dates
)

SELECT
    CASHDATE
    ,DATENAME(dw,CASHDATE) CashDateDayOfWeek
    ,NextBusinessDay
    ,DATENAME(dw,NextBusinessDay) NextBusinessDayDayofWeek
FROM
    cteNextBizDays
```

One of the considerations you need to think about when using `DATEPART(dw,Date)` is what the **DATEFRIST** setting is.  By Comparing with DATENAME you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` function:

```
DECLARE @CASHDATE datetime='2016-12-03' 
SELECT
    CashDate = @CASHDATE,
    NextBusinessDay = 
        DATEADD(DAY,
                CASE 
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @CASHDATE) % 7 > 3 
                        THEN 7 - DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @CASHDATE) % 7 
                    ELSE 1 
                END,
                @CASHDATE
        )
```

The `DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @CASHDATE) % 7` determines what day `@CASHDATE` is. Based on that, add the necessary number of days up to the next Monday.