# Is there an easy way to determine the next business day from a date with weekends and holidays included in the calculation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a future table which shows holidays and weekends along with calendar dates and I want to add a next business day field to that based on Holidays and Weekends.

For example: January 2nd 2020 is a holiday and so is January 1st. January 1st 2020 is a wednesday, so the next business day should be January 3rd. (skips the 2nd, friday is a business day).

Is there an easy function or loop which can do this simply? I only need to do it once so i'm not worried too much about not utilizing a set operation.

I had created what i assumed was the worlds worst case statement, but I realized that solution was just clunky and not supportable.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to define your holidays somewhere.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Including DDL and usable data makes it easier for us to help. A picture of data, not so much. That said, Eric Brandt had it almost right: the `Min( [date] )` greater than a given date for which `HldyInd = 'N' and WeekendInd = 'N'` ought to be the next business day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment but from what I have gathered... no, there is not a function provided by SQL Server but you can write a simple function like the one done in this post [Declare date, then add next business day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985656/declare-date-then-add-next-business-day)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks , I just used a derived subquery to allow incorrect dates to populate when there was a holiday to consider, then rolled those up to another layer and added an extra day.
Not the most elegant, but worked for my scenario.

```
select 
 a.date 
,a.day
,a.firstOfMonth
,a.MonthName
,a.week
,a.dayofWeek
,a.hldyInd
,a.weekendInd
,case when a.Nbdtemp IN ('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-20','2020-05-25','2020-07-03','2020-11-26','2020-12-25') then dateadd(day,1,nbdtemp) else Nbdtemp end as NxtBusinessDay
into #final
from

(
select t.*,
case when t.dayofweek not in ('Friday','Saturday') and t.HldyInd = 'N' then DATEADD(day,1,date) 
     when t.dayofweek = 'Friday' and t.hldyind = 'N' then dateadd(day,3,date) 
     when t.dayofweek = 'Saturday' and t.hldyind = 'N' then dateadd(day,2,date)  
     when t.hldyind = 'Y' then dateadd(day,1,date) end as Nbdtemp
 from #updtdim t
 ) as a
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is create Holidays table, and enter each holiday every year. After that, you can easy to give a day and find the next working day.

Here is my function to get how many working days between start and end day. You can easy to modify and get next business day.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Holidays](
[Date] [date] NULL,
[Description] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetWorkingDays]
(
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @ResultVar int = 0;
DECLARE @dt date = @StartDate;

WHILE @EndDate >= @dt BEGIN
    IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) < 6 BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Date FROM Holidays WHERE Date=@dt) BEGIN
            SET @ResultVar = @ResultVar + 1;
        END
    END
    SET @dt = DATEADD(DAY,1,@dt);
END 

RETURN @ResultVar;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
create table dbo.HolidayList(Holiday date)
insert into HolidayList(Holiday)values
('2019-07-01T00:00:00.000'),('2019-07-09T00:00:00.000'),('2019-08-01T00:00:00.000'),
('2019-08-02T00:00:00.000'),('2019-08-05T00:00:00.000'),('2019-09-02T00:00:00.000'),
('2019-10-14T00:00:00.000'),('2019-11-11T00:00:00.000'),('2019-12-25T00:00:00.000'),
('2019-12-26T00:00:00.000'),('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000'),('2020-02-10T00:00:00.000'),
('2020-02-17T00:00:00.000'),('2020-03-17T00:00:00.000'),('2020-04-10T00:00:00.000'),
('2020-04-13T00:00:00.000'),('2020-04-23T00:00:00.000'),('2020-05-18T00:00:00.000'),
('2020-05-25T00:00:00.000'),('2020-06-24T00:00:00.000'),('2020-07-01T00:00:00.000'),
('2020-07-09T00:00:00.000'),('2020-07-30T00:00:00.000'),('2020-07-31T00:00:00.000')
go
create function dbo.IsWeekday(@Date date) returns bit
begin
  return case when DATEDIFF(day,'0001-01-01T00:00:00.000',@Date)
    % 7 < 5 then 1 else 0 end
end
go
create function dbo.IsHoliday(@Date date)returns bit
begin
  return case when @Date in(select Holiday from HolidayList) then 1 else 0 end
end
go
create function dbo.IsWorkDay(@Date date)returns bit
begin
  return case when dbo.IsWeekday(@Date)=1 and dbo.IsHoliday(@Date)=0 then 1 else 0 end
end
go
create function dbo.WorkdayFollowing(@Date date)returns date
begin
  declare @D date = DATEADD(day,1,@date)
  while dbo.isworkday(@D)=0 
    begin
      set @D = DATEADD(day,1,@D)
    end
  return @D
end
go



declare @d date = '2019-06-01T00:00:00.000'
while @d < '2019-09-01T00:00:00.000'
begin
  set @d=DATEADD(day,1,@d)
  select @d, dbo.workdayfollowing(@d)
end
```